# How to set that data whole area in gridview?

Tags: c#

Hello, I am using the dataGridview control to display some data, but my problem is I have one or two columns of data, the columns  will appear in  a small part in gridview instead of filling all available space. I want the data to take up all available area in the datagrid. How can I do This? thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the Column Fill mode.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171605.aspx